# Removing NA from Column based on Condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have a dataframe where based on the condition of two of the columns, I want to remove the rows with NA's from a different column.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
removerows<-ifelse(df$MONTH==12 & 
df$YEAR==2015,
df[complete.cases(df$Retlisher),],
df[!complete.cases(df$Retlisher),])
```

When I try this, R crashes. This is the original dataframe:

```
  Place1234   We_source Wevisetiser   MONTH YEAR Weater.Size Revenue QP.TERuests Opportunities PaTP.WQpreOPIons
1                             <NA> MTD: 12 2015       LARGE       0      219768             0                0
2            abcdefghij abcdefghij      12 2015     UNKNOWN       0           0             2                0
3            abcdefghij abcdefghij MTD: 12 2015     UNKNOWN       0           0             2                0
4           1ek4nd2 (4)    1ek4nd2      12 2015     UNKNOWN       0           0             0                0
5                             <NA>      12 2015       LARGE       0      219768             0                0
6            abcdefghij abcdefghij      12 2015     UNKNOWN       0           0             2                0
  Weep Amount Weep.Rate Overall.Weep.Rate WALS.Rate RET OPT Retlisher Placement.Type Platform.Type Geography
1    0      0         0                 0         0   0   0      <NA>           <NA>          <NA>      <NA>
2    0      0         0                 0         0   0   0      <NA>           <NA>          <NA>      <NA>
3    0      0         0                 0         0   0   0      <NA>           <NA>          <NA>      <NA>
4    0      0         0                 0         0   0   0      <NA>           <NA>          <NA>      <NA>
5    0      0         0                 0         0   0   0      <NA>           <NA>          <NA>      <NA>
6    0      0         0                 0         0   0   0      <NA>           <NA>          <NA>      <NA>
  Type1
1  <NA>
2  <NA>
3  <NA>
4  <NA>
5  <NA>
6  <NA>
```

Comment: Why don't you try to explain the logic of your current approach? From your original `data.frame`, which rows do you want to keep?

Comment: I want to remove rows when the NA's occur in the Retlisher column when Month=12 and Year=2015 @AnandaMahto. This is only the first 6 lines of the dataframe so there are occurences when Retlisher does have a value

Comment: df[df$MONTH!=12&df$YEAR!=2015&!is.na(df$Retlisher), ]

Comment: @VenYao I am not sure that is a possible solution, as I believe @R Guru still needs to keep observations where Retlisher is populated while YEAR == 2015 and MONTH == 12.

Comment: @Justin your right, I actually do need to keep Year == 2015 and MONTH == 12. Back to drawing board I guess, I just checked and it isn't correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple subsetting solution. One of many ways to do what you are looking for. Does this solve your problem?

```
df=data.frame(YEAR= c(2015, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2013), 
     MONTH=c(12,12,12,11,10),
     Retlisher=as.factor(c(NA,NA, 15,15,16)))


 df=df[(df$MONTH == 12 & df$YEAR==2015 & !is.na(df$Retlisher)) | 
    (!df$MONTH ==12) | (!df$YEAR == 2015),]

> df
  YEAR MONTH Retlisher
2 2014    12      <NA>
3 2015    12        15
4 2015    11        15
5 2013    10        16
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. It didn't remove the <NA> in the Retlisher column when Month = 12 and Year = 2015. Do you think it didn't do it because there is < > around the NA?

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me with NA formatted as <NA>. Can you make a small reproduction of your data and post it here?

Comment: I think it isn't working because Month is a character for me.

Comment: MONTH = chr, YEAR = num, and Retlisher = Factor

Comment: Try removing the non numeric characters from month and converting to numeric. Here you go!  df$MONTH=as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", df$MONTH))

Comment: there are not just numbers in the month though, i have values like "MTD: 12"

Comment: I understand, that is why I included the regular expression above to remove the non-numeric characters. Are these non-numeric characters necessary for your analysis? Alternatively, if you don't want to remove the non numeric characters, just use the regular expression to create a new column and use that one for the subsetting.